# Chart.js How to actualize canvas due to new x-axis range typed by user

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

**What I have:**

On chart.js there is a canvas which has exact values on x-axis e.g. from 1 to 9
There will be a possibility for user to type a new range which user who is interested to see another view, let say it is limited scope. In me repo I limited this function and typed values start = 3 and end = 6 (this new limit - from 3 to 6 I want to see).

I've already have a method which constraints data presented on graph, but due to the fact that upgrade button is outside the `canvas` I don't know how to force chart to be upgraded.

**What I need:**
How to force chart to be updated?

me repo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng2-charts-new-range-x-axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When updating the chart `labels`, you also need to update the corresponding values in the `data` array of your `dataset`.

There's no need however to invoke `chart.update()`, `ng2-charts` is built in a way that Angular change detection will take care of updating the chart as soon as its data or options change.

You could change the `updateChart` method as follows to make it work:

```
updateChart(start, end) {
  const labels = [];
  const data = []; 
  this.lineChartLabels.forEach((l, i) => {
    if (l >= start && l <= end) {
      labels.push(l); 
      data.push(this.seriesB[i]);
    }
  });
  this.lineChartLabels = labels;
  this.lineChartData[0].data = data;
}
```

Please take a look at your amended [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng2-charts-new-range-x-axis-ldq8te?file=app%2Fline-chart.component.ts).

Comment: Wow! You are great! This is very useful, in fact I have a lot of curves presented on chart and I even don't have to use this line of code `this.lineChartData[0].data = data;`
(I also updated stackblitz).

Comment: Values presented on chart are get from database and are stored in other way